# QtWebEngine 32bit dll is needed

Tags: qt, qtwebengine

I am done with all building activities of **qwebengine** on **32bit msvc2015 platform using VS2017 compiler**. I finally fed up with the build logs and errors.
Can anyone please share the below dlls for **32bit support**?

1. Qt5WebEngine.dll
2. Qt5WebEngineCore.dll
3. Qt5WebEngineWidgets.dll
4. QtWebEngineProcess.exe
5. qwebengine_convert_dict.exe

I need these dlls to support of 32bit application.

Comment: Sorry, but SO is for programming questions. Not for asking locations or suggestions for 3rd party things or libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I built the .dll's using VS2017 as compiler with MSVC2015 qt qmake.
Follow the below steps to build your own webengine support for 32bit application.

1. Open "*X86 native tools command prompt for VS 2017*"
2. Command: **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvarsall.bat" x86**
3. Command: **C:\Qt\Qt5.11.1\5.11.1\msvc2015\bin\qmake.exe C:\Qt\Qt5.11.1\5.11.1\Src\qtwebengine -- -webengine-proprietary-codecs**
4. Command: **"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.16.27023\bin\Hostx86\x86\nmake.exe"**

It will take time to build (apprx. 4-5hrs)
Then your dlls will be placed in the path "*C:\Qt\Qt5.11.1\5.11.1\msvc2015\bin*".
Enjoy and do coding lovely even to support 32bit applications.